# asp.net mvc sending jquery generated hidden field to controller action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have preloaded hidden fields on the web form. these hidden fields are sent successfully to the controller when the jquery button is clicked

```
<input type ="hidden" class="serviceslist " value="1"/>
<input type ="hidden" class="serviceslist " value="2"/>
```

i am adding additional hidden fields by clicking the **addmore**  button. these hidden fields are not be send to the controller when the jquery button is clicked . what might be the problem? are they not present in the dom?

```
<input type ="hidden" class="serviceslist " value="3"/>
<input type ="hidden" class="serviceslist " value="4"/>


  $('#addmoreservices').on('click', function () {
        var url = "/Quotation/AddmoreServices/";

        var serviceslist = $(".serviceslist ").serialize();        
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { serviceslist: serviceslist },
            cache: false,
            contenttype: 'application/json',
            dataType: "json",              
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {           

                return false;
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
```

this is the code of the button i am trying to send whole bunch of hidden fields(preloaded and created) to the controller. the preloaded are being sent and created ones are left behind)

Comment: serialize only process input with a name

Comment: Can you add the code to add the input fields dynamically?? Or is it so that you add input fields in this function's success callback??

Comment: The solution would be to make the 'click' handler of

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the element dynamically so it is not registered when you set the click handler.
 Therefor also call the event handler once you have created the dynamic element

You have not shown enough code , therefor difficult to tell the exact solution,

Comment: change the first line of where you attached event handler with `$(document.body).on('click','#addmoreservices' , function () { ` , this will attach event handler for dynamic element also

Answer (score 0):

Add unique names to the fields. Don't use the same name over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

if your input has a name,the serialize() can process

```
<input type ="hidden" class="serviceslist " value="1" name="a" />
```

but if all your input name is "a",the serialize result is

```
a=1&a=2&a=3....
```

i think that is not what you want
maybe you want

```
1,2,3,4....
```

try use

```
$(".serviceslist").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the 'click' event handler a separate js function like

```
$('#addmoreservices').on('click', addHandler)

var addHandler = function(){...};
```

Then on the **addmore** button click handler, after you add the new input to dom, again bind the addmoreservices button click handler 'addHandler'. This will include the newly created inputs in the 'addHandler' function.